# Create script that contains commands thatn requires input and spawn subshell

Tags: bash, shell-script

I generate keytab for kerberos using:

```
ktutil

=================================
add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac
add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
list
wkt  path/myKeytab.keytab
exit

==================================

ls -al path/myKeytab.keytab

klist -ekt /path/myKeytab.keytab

kinit -kt path/myKeytab.keytab <domain>
klist
```

And i would like to create scropt for this that takes password as argument and generates the keytab.

I have two questions:

the `ktutil` spawns subshell ( if its correct name ) that wants the commands.

1. How to make the script call `ktutil`and then everything up until exit ( which exits the subshell ) to be commands inside it?
2. The `add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac` commands require input from user, how to pass the input to script?

`$1 > add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac` or similliar tricks i have googled does not work.

From what i have researched, this script should work:

```
password="$1"

printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p  <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac" | ktutil
printf "%b" "$password"
printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96" | ktutil
printf "%b" "$password"
printf "%b" "list" | ktutil
printf "%b" "wkt path/myKeytab.keytab" | ktutil
printf "%b" "exit" | ktutil
```

And it works to some degree, however the `"add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96"` promts for password which `printf` on the next line does not inject the value. I tried to change it to

```
password="$1"

echo "$password" | printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p  <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac" | ktutil
echo "$password" | printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96" | ktutil
printf "%b" "list" | ktutil
printf "%b" "wkt myKeytab.keytab" | ktutil
printf "%b" "exit" | ktutil
```

Then i tried routing in in one command:

```
password="$1"

printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac\n
$password\n
 add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 0 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n
$password\n
list\n
wkt myKeytab.keytab\n
exit" | ktutil

ls -al myKeytab.keytab

klist -ekt myKeytab.keytab

kinit -kt smyKeytab.keytab <domain>
klist
```

This results in:

```
ktutil:  <password>
ktutil: Unknown request "<password>".  Type "?" for a request list.
```

Which means somehow the password is wrongly parsed? However when i use:

```
password="$1"

echo "$1" | printf "%b" "add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 1 -e arcfour-hmac\n
 add_entry -password -p <domain> -k 0 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96\n
list
wkt myKeytab.keytab
exit" | ktutil

ls -al myKeytab.keytab

klist -ekt myKeytab.keytab

kinit -kt smyKeytab.keytab <domain>
klist
```

The script finished but the kinit complains about:kinit: `Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials`
which means the password was wrongly parsed, as when i manaually add these commands without script it works

Comment: "the ktutil spawns subshell ( if its correct name ) that wants the commands." No, that should be a native executable in any implementation I'd be aware of. No subshells involved. Also, what do you mean "if its correct name"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it has been quite a time since i had to implement bash scripts so my terminology is rusty. when start ktutil it starts ktutil shell? executable? basicly says "ktutil: " even if i execute  `ktutil add_entry ....` if it makes sense, so even if i run this from script i end up in "ktutil:" window or how to explain it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller updated question

Comment: you need to pipe all your  `printf` outputs into **one** execution of `ktutil`, not into five separate ones!

Comment: @MarcusMüller i did so - updated the question

Comment: `echo "$password" | printf "%b"...` is the same as `printf "%b"...`, because printf doesn't read stdin.

Comment: If ktutil reads password from a terminal, then any text passed to stdin would not be processed as if a password was typed into a password prompt. Instead, it will be processed as input if/when stdin is read. One related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/how-to-pass-the-password-to-su-sudo-ssh-without-overriding-the-tty

Comment: @Vilinkameni so how can i make it read the password? The question you have posted is aobut sudo that has explicit command for this

Comment: @Vilinkameni updated question

Comment: The accepted answer to the question I linked has a clue: using [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Check ktutil documentation to see if there is a better way though (for sudo it was setting up private key authorization correctly).